# Cant verify smart card PIN using APDU command

Tags: java, smartcard, verify, sim-card

I'm using Java javax.smartcard library to read data from smart card(SIM card). But i can't get my code working to verify my PIN. Here is my code:

```
public class CopyOfCardReader {

public static final CommandAPDU SELECT_FILE_EEEE = new CommandAPDU(new byte[] { 0x00, (byte) 0xA4, 0x01, 0x0C, 0x02, (byte) 0xEE, (byte) 0xEE });
public static final CommandAPDU SELECT_MASTER_FILE = new CommandAPDU(new byte[] { 0x00, (byte) 0xA4, 0x00, 0x0C });
public static final CommandAPDU DISABLE_PIN = new CommandAPDU(new byte[] { 0x00, (byte) 0x26, 0x00, 0x00 });

public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {

        TerminalFactory factory = TerminalFactory.getDefault();
        List<CardTerminal> terminals = null;

        terminals = factory.terminals().list();

        System.out.println("Terminals: " + terminals);
        CardTerminal terminal = terminals.get(0);
        Card card = terminal.connect("T=0");
        System.out.println("card: " + card);
        ATR atr = card.getATR();
        System.out.print("ATR: ");

        for (byte b : atr.getBytes()) {
            System.out.print(b);
        }
        System.out.println();
        CardChannel channel = card.getBasicChannel();


        byte[] pin = "1234".getBytes();
        byte arg0 = (byte) 0x00;
        byte arg1 = (byte) 0x20;
        byte arg2 = (byte) 0x00;
        byte arg3 = (byte) 0x01;
        CommandAPDU command = new CommandAPDU(arg0, arg1, arg2, arg3, pin);
        ResponseAPDU request = channel.transmit(command);
        System.out.println("answer pin verify request: " + request.toString()); // response

        ResponseAPDU rmaster = channel.transmit(SELECT_MASTER_FILE);
        System.out.println("answer rmaster file: " + rmaster.toString()); // response
        System.out.println();

        ResponseAPDU rPinDiable = channel.transmit(new CommandAPDU(new byte[] { (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x26, 0x00, 0x00 }));
        System.out.println("answer DISABLE PIN: " + rPinDiable.toString()); // response

        ResponseAPDU rverify2 = channel.transmit(new CommandAPDU(0x00, 0x20, 0x00, 0x01, new byte[] { 0x31, 0x32, 0x33, 0x34, (byte) 0xFF, (byte) 0xFF, (byte) 0xFF, (byte) 0xFF }));
        System.out.println("answer rverify2 pin2: " + rverify2.toString()); // response

        byte[] pin2 = "1234".getBytes();
        byte arg02 = (byte) 0x01;
        byte arg12 = (byte) 0x26;
        byte arg22 = (byte) 0x00;
        byte arg32 = (byte) 0x01;
        CommandAPDU command2 = new CommandAPDU(arg02, arg12, arg22, arg32, pin2);
        ResponseAPDU request2 = channel.transmit(command2);
        System.out.println("answer pin disable request: " + request2.toString()); // response

        byte[] baReadUID = new byte[5];
        baReadUID = new byte[] { (byte) 0xFF, (byte) 0xCA, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00 };
        command = new CommandAPDU(baReadUID);
        ResponseAPDU r = channel.transmit(new CommandAPDU(new byte[] { 0X00, (byte) 0XA4, 0X00, 0X00, 0X02, 0X3F, 0X00 }));
        System.out.println("answer r UID: " + r.toString()); // response
        System.out.print("UUID: ");
        for (byte b : r.getData()) {
            System.out.print(b); // response
        }
        System.out.println();

        card.disconnect(false);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}}
```

And below is program output:

```
Terminals: [PC/SC terminal Gemalto USB SmartCard Reader 0]
card: PC/SC card in Gemalto USB SmartCard Reader 0, protocol T=0, state OK
ATR: 5959-106064-126-1110036-155151-1120
answer pin verify request: ResponseAPDU: 2 bytes, SW=6708
answer rmaster file: ResponseAPDU: 2 bytes, SW=9000

answer DISABLE PIN: ResponseAPDU: 2 bytes, SW=6708
answer rverify2 pin2: ResponseAPDU: 2 bytes, SW=6a88
answer pin disable request: ResponseAPDU: 2 bytes, SW=6708
answer r UID: ResponseAPDU: 37 bytes, SW=9000
UUID: 9833-126212033-1252630-917-1281113-125236-15-11815-11731585-1-586-11210-12511
```

Reading master file and UUID is successful but all other instructions are failed. Is there someone who know what is problem with my code? Please help.

Comment: Your AID seems to be wrong... `6A82` means "application could not be found".

Comment: Ok i removed that command for sellecting application. Besides that why my PIN verification dont work?
Why i get error 6708 "length incorrect"?

Answer (score 2):

You should definitely read [GMS 11.11](http://www.etsi.org/deliver/etsi_ts/100900_100999/100977/08.14.00_60/ts_100977v081400p.pdf).

Regarding the VERIFY part, try:

```
byte[] pin = { (byte)0x31, (byte)0x32, (byte)0x33, (byte)0x34, (byte)0xFF, (byte)0xFF, (byte)0xFF, (byte)0xFF};
```

as PIN is 8 bytes long with shorter values being padded with `0xFF` (the `0x31`, `0x32`, `0x33`... bytes represent ASCII characters `'1'`,`'2'`,`'3'`...).

This is what the `67XX` status word tells (incorrect parameter `P3` which holds length in this case). See section 9.4 for status codes you may encounter.

Some random notes:

- Your APDU commands should have the `CLA` byte set to `0xA0` (i.e. the first byte -- the `arg0` one).
- Most of your other commands are quite weird -- I would recommend to follow GSM 11.11.
- Consider separating printed bytes with commas (what you are getting now is unreadable).
- Beware you can damage your card with such a fierce research.

Good luck!